# Import users to aspnet_membership table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am trying to import 1000 users to aspnet_membership table using TSQL. Could anyone please point me to the right direction whether this is possible at all?

The requirement is to:

1. Create Users and Profiles.
2. Generate password.
3. Email password to end users.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to do this using TSQL directly?  You could do this very easily with a simple app in C# using the SqlMembershipProvider.

Comment: will be a routine process and I'm thinking of using SSIS Package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use  unencrypted password format then you can just call **dbo.aspnet_Membership_CreateUser** stored procedure from your SQL to create users. It takes a bunch of params;
    *@ApplicationName

    @UserName

    @Password

    @PasswordSalt

    @Email

    @PasswordQuestion

    @PasswordAnswer

    @IsApproved

    @CurrentTimeUtc

    @CreateDate

    @UniqueEmail

    @PasswordFormat

    @UserId    (output)*

You can generate password in TSQL and you can send emails from TSQL. This stored procedure: **dbo.aspnet_Profile_SetProperties** would set Profile properties.

If you need hashed or encrypted passwords .. then probably you have to write some admin code that uses Membership and Profile providers. It should be fairly easy to do so. Providers have all the methods that are needed to generate and encrypt passwords. 
To create users you would just call:

**CreateUser** 
*( string username,
                                                   string password,
                                                   string email,
                                                   string passwordQuestion,
                                                   string passwordAnswer,
                                                   bool   isApproved,
                                                   object providerUserKey,
                                                   out    MembershipCreateStatus status )*

method and pass the data in. The encryption will happen inside the method.

So TSQL could work if you do not need to encrypt or hash passwords. Otherwise it wouldbe some coding .. but really minimal.

Comment: thanks but, what should I put for these params: PasswordSalt,@urrentTimeUtc,passwordFormat

Comment: 0 for paswordFormat (it will mean clear text, ,@urrentTimeUtc - current date UTC, PasswordSalt will not be used for clear text passwords .. so anything probably will work.

Comment: The only thing I can't figure out is how to fake the userid and password salt?!? I can't create memberships with the configuration so I have to input them using the database. I can't put a `NULL` value in hoping it will make one up for me so I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Well, AFAIK - there is no automated wizard to do this and you would need to code through it. You can import the users and profiles using SQL statements. However GeneratePassword and Emailing is something you might want to consider as a seperate process to make it more loosely coupled.